# Efficient patent brainstorming session

Tags: meetings, facilitation, startup

We have an existing application. What are the most efficient ways to get patent ideas out from a group of people during a brainstorming session? For example, brainstorm ideas and list them on a board or ask participants to write ideas down on stickers and then collect the stickers and then use them as a base. By efficient I mean both quantity and areas these ideas cover.

Comment: List-generating questions are almost always off-topic on PMSE. Instead, please explain what you've already tried, and what problems you have had with your specific approach.

Comment: do you really expect to get a patentable idea out of a brainstorming session?

Comment: We can't measure "efficiency" without some notion of value.   As a general rule, the most efficient way to conduct a brainstorming session is to couple the incentives to the results you want and suppress incentives that interfere with the results you want (that's the definition of brainstorming). Do you know what results you want? More ideas? More high quality ideas? A single idea that is the optimum quality?   Since you haven't defined "patent ideas"?, it is very difficult to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at '[The Design Sprint](http://www.gv.com/sprint/)' as an alternative to brainstorming. Its a funnel like method to go from generating new idea's to a validated concept. (I have executed one and I was greatly surprised about how effective it is. Also just reading the book is worth your-while to get new idea's how to facilitate "brainstorming" sessions that do not stifle innovation, including good examples.)

This because brainstorming sessions are the least effective way of coming up with new innovative idea's.

From [Why Most Brainstorming Sessions Are Useless](http://www.forbes.com/sites/nataliepeace/2012/04/09/why-most-brainstorming-sessions-are-useless/):

> There have been several studies done on the effectiveness of
>   brainstorming, and the results are disappointing.
>
> ...
>
> He goes on to say that “people are more creative away from the crowd.
>   It is a universal phenomenon emerging in work across the world,
>   including America, India, Thailand and Japan. In short – for seventy
>   years, people have been using brainstorming to stifle–not stimulate
>   their creative juices.”